# Windows 7 Copydialog

Tags: windows-7

how to ALWAYS show the "more information" info when copying files?
must be a .reg-entry or something like this...

Comment: Ah, glad to know I'm not the only one who almost always expands that dialog!

Answer (score 3):

As Sathya says, there is no such way.

Perhaps you're better off using TeraCopy? It's faster, more accurate and wont leave you stuck in the middle of a failed copy operation.

http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php

(my 2c)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as of now, [there](http://www.vistaheads.com/forums/microsoft-public-windows-vista-general/268896-file-copy-move-more-information-auto-open.html) seems to be [no way](http://www.vistax64.com/vista-general/130120-always-show-more-information-when-copying-files.html) to make [it permament](http://www.windows7taskforce.com/view/2229).

Answer (score 0):

How about an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) script to look for appearances of that dialog and, assuming the dialog is always the same size, left-click the location of the "More information" button?

Comment: I agree with you in this case, even though it's the answer I gave.  I agree that you should have an option to do it automatically.  However, in the absence of any solution at all...  *shrug*

Comment: It's hardly an elegant solution, but it actually works - unlike anything else.